# iOS GoogleSignIn is returning an expired id token

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am trying to retrieve from Google an id token to send to my backend server.

The problem is that **the id token that I am receiving is already expired**, so it is not valid to my server.

```
 // MARK: - Google auth
extension LoginView: GIDSignInDelegate {
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        // Check for sign in error
        if let error = error {
            if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
            } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }
        
        guard let u = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser, let email = u.profile.email, let eDate =  u.authentication.idTokenExpirationDate, let idToken = u.authentication.idToken else { return }
    
        print(">> ", eDate)
        self.register(email: email, token: idToken)
    }
}
```

The date: `>>  2020-10-01 08:09:19 +0000`(Currently is 09:10 hours)

Thanks